# JavaScript works with inline svg but not with external linked svg?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I do not know how to apply this code for an external svg.

I'm working with Illustrator from where I exported the svg. In HTML, I want to grab the path name of and print it in a tooltip. This works while I use the svg inline.

I tried to read about ways how to implement an external svg the same way, but without any success. Any help what I can do to get the same code to work with an external svg?

With the external svg, I do not even get the mouse position while I hover over the svg anymore

The working HTML code:

```js
var myImage = document.getElementsByTagName("path");
var text = document.getElementById("show");

for (var i = 0; i < myImage.length; i++) {
  myImage[i].addEventListener('mouseover', show);
  myImage[i].addEventListener('mouseout', hide);
}

function show() {
  var myID = this.id;
  text.innerHTML = myID;
  document.getElementById("show").style.display = "block";
}

function hide() {
  var myID = this.id;
  text.innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById("show").style.display = "none";
}

var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById('show');

window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX,
    y = e.clientY;
  tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
  tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
};
```

```css
#show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 56.69 56.69"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#1d1d1b;}</style></defs><g><path id="Black_Layer" class="cls-1" d="M16,7.7c0.6,0.4-1,1.1-0.9,1.8c0.1,0.5,0.4,1,0.8,1.3c0.6,0.5,1.5,0.6,2.2,0.5c0.8-0.2,1.4-0.7,1.8-1.4c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-0.9C20.1,6.9,17.2,6.8,16,7.7z"/></g></svg>
<div id="show" style="position: absolute; left: 100px; background-color:aqua; padding: 5px;"></div>
```

When I replace the svg code with an external svg like this:

```
<object id='Ebene_1' data="Test-01.svg" type="image/svg+xml" >Your browser doesn't support SVG</object>
```

With Paul's help i was able to grab the elements of the external SVG, now. Actually it works in Google Chrome, too (maybe i had some cache problems as i thought it wouldn't)

```
window.onload=function() {
    var a = document.getElementById("Ebene_1");
    var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
    var myImage = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("path");

for (var i = 0; i < myImage.length; i++) {
  myImage[i].addEventListener('mouseover', show);
  myImage[i].addEventListener('mouseout', hide);
}

var text = document.getElementById("show");

svgDoc.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX,
    y = e.clientY;
  text.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
  text.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
};

function show() {
  var myID = this.id;
  text.innerHTML = myID;
  document.getElementById("show").style.display = "block";
}

function hide() {
  var myID = this.id;
  text.innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById("show").style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Comment: the object contents are a separate document, get that document and proceed as you do already. E.g. https://benfrain.com/selecting-svg-inside-tags-with-javascript/

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work... Actually it seems i do not know how to get this seperate document... i edited my post so you can see what i did. I found the link of benfrain.com ,too. Couldn't help me... and i loose the mouse movement, too?

Comment: Are you waiting for the `<object>` to load the SVG? If not your code will fail.  You need to put the code that accesses inside a load event, as the linked page does (eg. `window.onload=function() { ... }`)

Comment: Actually it doesn't work in Google chrome... for var svgDoc = a.contentDocument; i get a error message: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLObjectElement': Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame. Any idea?

Comment: That is because the SVG file is no from the same origin. For security reasons, you are only allowed access if it is from the same origin. A possible solution is to use a proxy on your local server that fetches the external SVG.

Comment: Hy Terry, i hosted the site on a public domain for testing on a server and it still keeps this message. So it's not a local issue, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll never be able to achieve that as the only way to gather the SVG shapes is through inline svg. Please read this article where you'll understand the basic concepts of SVG in the browser.
https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Also, in case you do not wish to modify your code I would recommend SVG Injector https://github.com/iconic/SVGInjector, which converts your `<img src="file.svg"` > to inline SVG on the fly.
By doing this, your code will work accordingly.

Comment: So you men it is not possible for Google Chrome as you mentioned "You'll never be able to achieve that ", as it works in Firefox and Safari so far? But maybe the injector would be the way to go as using inline svg is not possible, as i would use different world maps it will overlaod the code of the basic Html.